# stm32f4 discovery board LED not blinking

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f4

I tested this code for all four inboard LEDs and an external LED.
All LEDs turned ON, but they don't blink.
Here is my code:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

void WaitaMoment (int time)
{
for (time = 0; time > 0; time--);
}

int main(void)
{
RCC -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;
GPIOD -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0;
GPIOD -> OTYPER &= ~ (GPIO_OTYPER_OT_14);
GPIOD -> OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR14;
GPIOD -> PUPDR &= ~ (GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR14);

//int time;
while(1)
{
    GPIOD -> BSRRL |= GPIO_BSRR_BS_14;
    //for (time=0; time < 200000; time++);
    WaitaMoment(200000);
    GPIOD -> BSRRH |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_14;
    WaitaMoment(200000);
    //for (time=0; time < 200000; time++);
}
}
```

What is my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure |= for GPIOD -> BSRRL &  BSRRH  is correct. Try just = rather than |=. Other than that, most likely is your GPIO isn't set up correctly. This line: GPIOD -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0; what is GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0 defined as? Should be 0x01 I think for GP output mode. Also, you're just ORing it, but what was the value befoe you ORed it?

Comment: From "Open Declaration": #define GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0                 ((uint32_t)0x10000000). So it is set as General Purpose Output Mode. I put = sign here but nothing changed. I also put = before BSRRL and BSRRH and nothing changed.

Comment: Does your debugger confirm  MODER  is set correctly? You didn't tell me what it was before you ORed it. My next guess would be you're trying to toggle the wrong GPIOs. It's impossible to know without seeing schematics.

Comment: Before I ORed it the value was 0x10000000. I don't know exactly how to analyze a debugger, but it shows this same value after ORing it. I am addressing the correct GPIO because the orange LED lights if GPIO is set as 13, the green lights for 12, the red for 14 and the blue for 15.

Comment: Well, it will show the same value after ORing it in this case. Do you understand what ORing and ANDing does? That's very important to know when doing this kind of stuff. Whaty does the debugger say the ODR register is set to after accessing BSSRH and L?

Comment: please provide a disassembly of these two functions

Comment: as pointed out you just write bsrr not read-modify-write.  you should use the same register for setting and resetting thus the whole point of the register.   you are sure your delay loop actually does something, as written it is dead code (and would get optimized out completely leaving leds "glow"ing or perhaps all on or all off depending)

Comment: Is `GPIO_BSRR_BR_14` a typo in the question or a typo in your code?  I believe the last R should be an S.

Comment: ... from @old_timer if a register is write-only with various bit-fields you can keep a shadow copy to modify and update and write to the register.

Comment: @WeatherVane not sure I understand, that register is there specifically so you dont have to do read-modify-writes like a generic data out type register, that was all I was meaning to say...I would have to look and see what a read even does a read-modify-write might do bad things although I assume reads are zeros on that register, but again would need to read up on it.

Comment: @old_timer I was inspired by your comment to make a general remark, in the case of a register with various bitfields which is not readable, but you need to preserve other bits which are not currently of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop in `WaitaMoment` does not iterate because it sets `time = 0` and then loops while `time > 0` which is never.  Change it so that the loop does not set `time = 0`.

```
void WaitaMoment (int time)
{
for (; time > 0; time--);
}
```

This loop may still not iterate if the compiler recognizes that it doesn't do anything and optimizes it away.  Make sure the delay is not getting optimized away or the LED may flash so fast that you cannot see the flashes.

As mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't use `|=` with BSRRL and BSRRH.  Write it like this instead.

```
GPIOD->BSRRL = GPIO_BSRR_BS_14;
WaitaMoment(200000);
GPIOD->BSRRH = GPIO_BSRR_BS_14;
WaitaMoment(200000);
```

And make sure you have spelled everything correctly (GPIO_BSRR_B**S**_14 not GPIO_BSRR_B**R**_14)

Comment: Answering all the comments, the debugger did not show any value for GPIO_BSRR_BR_14. Now both values are 0x4000, which matches value 1 for pin D14. BR is reset, so I thought that I should be BSetting to light and RSetting to turn off the LEDs. Now I wrote the for loop as for (time; time>0; time--). The BSRRL and BSRRH does not have OR in it and both are now BS_14. It worked. Thank you a lot. I will study more about ORing, ANDing, etc.

Comment: Great spot by kk, I hadn't even glanced at the delay loop. This shows the value of a debugger where you can set break points and step though. You would have immediately seen that the LEDs *do* switch on and off and soon realised it was your delay loop not working.